# How to refresh data in Cognos?

Tags: javascript, html, cognos

I have report in Congos. There is a Table with data. I don't want to use refresh because I don't want to set prompts again. I would like to add some kind of auto-refresh... Is someone know how to do it? When I add HTML file with refresh command directly from cogon's site.
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/setting-auto-refresh-cognos-report

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

And report has been refreshed but it back to main page...

Some can help?

Answer (score 0):

In 11.1.7 there is an auto refresh sample report which uses customer JavaScript to do what you are looking for.  The report is called Auto refresh and uses the the following file and configuration for the custom control:

/bi/samples/js/AutoRefresh/AutoRefresh.js
{"Seconds": 15}

Answer (score 0):

Cognos 11 has in the tool box, the first option, custom controls

You can add it in structure view just below the Page body

It may help to add the time to the page just to see it working

The properties will look like this

```
UI Type: None
Module Path: /ibmcognos/bi/samples/js/AutoRefresh/AutoRefresh.js
Configuration: 10   (the number you enter is the delay in seconds for refresh)
```

There is a potential bug in the javascript that you might need to fix, here is the apar:
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PH20250